# spring security login not working with oracle

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on spring security login using jdbc-user-service. It is working on Mysql but not on oracle. I am using oracle 11 XE.

The queries I have mentioned in  tag are correct because those return expected rows when I run those on oracle console.

The datasource is :

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${datasource.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

in sessionFactory bean hibernate dialect for oracle is given.

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
```

Same code works for mysql and not on oracle. The application control is redirected to login page which I have set in spring security file. This means it is getting username & password correctly.

```
<form-login login-page="/landing" default-target-url="/home"
        authentication-failure-url="/landing?msg=cw" />
```

The authentication provider code in spring security xml is :

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query=" 
    select USERNAME as username, PASSWORD as password,'true' as enabled from 
    users where USERNAME=?"

            authorities-by-username-query=" select u.USERNAME 
    as username, r.ROLE as authority from users u, roles r, user_roles 
    ur where u.USER_ID = ur.USER_ID and ur.ROLE_ID = r.id and u.USER_ID = (SELECT 
    USER_ID from users where USERNAME = ?)" />

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Is there anything need to be configured in order to use oracle in spring security ?

UPDATE : I set spring security debug and this is what is printing after I try to login.

```
INFO : Spring Security Debugger - 

************************************************************

Request received for '/j_spring_security_check':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7262b6

servletPath:/j_spring_security_check
pathInfo:null

  Security filter chain: [
  ConcurrentSessionFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


INFO : Spring Security Debugger - 

************************************************************

Request received for '/landing?msg=cw':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@bf1a4a

servletPath:/landing
pathInfo:null

Security filter chain: [
ConcurrentSessionFilter
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
LogoutFilter
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
BasicAuthenticationFilter
RequestCacheAwareFilter
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
SessionManagementFilter
ExceptionTranslationFilter
FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************
```

Comment: I don't see any error behind. It is sending back to login page even if   credentials are correct.

Comment: increase log level to debug and see what messages being printed by spring security.

Comment: Could you post the authentication provider code?

Comment: @Jigar Parekh ... Please see the update.

Comment: @kmb385 please see the updates made.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and after hours of research i found the solution. The User Details of spring security wants a boolean value on enabled and 'true' on Oracle doesn't work. I fix it replacing this:

```
users-by-username-query=" 
select USERNAME as username, PASSWORD as password,'true' as enabled from 
users where USERNAME=?"
```

To this:

```
users-by-username-query=" 
select USERNAME as username, PASSWORD as password,1 as enabled from 
users where USERNAME=?"
```

It works!. I found the solution reading [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spring-user-group-peru/BkN7cLggHhU).

Comment: Thanks. This is quite old post of mine. Later I replaced the spring security code with custom authentication using DaoAuthenticationManager. Appreciate your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc14.jar (pending Oracle Version) in your classpath.