# oracle database connecting issue using spring security and custom user service

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, oracle11g

**I am new to spring mvc and spring security.I want to provide security for our login form in terms of account lockout mechanism whenever user enter wrong credentials three times.But my data access bean class defined in spring_security.xml is unable to connect with oracle database.So how to solve this issue.Thank you.**

here is my spring_security.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('role_admin')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/welcome" always-use-default-target="false"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />

    </http>




    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.dxb.users.service.CustomUserDetailsService">
            <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="select * from users where username = ?"/>
            <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="select username, role from user_roles where username =?" />
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </beans:bean>   




        <beans:bean id="userDetailsDao" class="com.dxb.users.dao.UserDetailsDaoImpl" >
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </beans:bean>




        <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.dxb.web.handler.LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider">
            <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
            <beans:property name="userDetailsDao" ref="userDetailsDao" />
        </beans:bean>

         <authentication-manager>

           <authentication-provider  ref="authenticationProvider"></authentication-provider>

        </authentication-manager> 



</beans:beans>
```

here is spring_database.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.7:1521/XE" />
        <property name="username" value="procdb" />
        <property name="password" value="procdbadmin" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

here is mvc_dispatcher_servlet

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dxb.*" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>


    </bean>

</beans>
```

and web.xml

```
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <display-name>Spring Security Application</display-name>


    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,
                    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

here the stack trace for above code

```
    Jul 27, 2016 4:16:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;D:\app\user\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext;%C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;D:\software\eclipse;;.
Jul 27, 2016 4:16:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:LoginAttempt' did not find a matching property.
Jul 27, 2016 4:16:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:test' did not find a matching property.
Jul 27, 2016 4:16:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringHibernateEx' did not find a matching property.
Jul 27, 2016 4:16:56 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 27, 2016 4:16:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 710 ms
Jul 27, 2016 4:16:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 27, 2016 4:16:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Jul 27, 2016 4:16:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'sdnext'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\b2bAER_v1.0\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\test\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:00 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:00 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Jul 27 16:17:00 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion performVersionChecks
INFO: You are running with Spring Security Core 3.2.3.RELEASE
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
INFO: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.3.RELEASE
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser parseInterceptUrlsForFilterInvocationRequestMap
INFO: Creating access control expression attribute 'hasRole('role_admin')' for /admin**
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder
INFO: Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter warning
WARNING: Configuration problem: Overriding globally registered AuthenticationManager
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter warning
WARNING: Configuration problem: Overriding globally registered AuthenticationManager
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter warning
WARNING: Configuration problem: Overriding globally registered AuthenticationManager
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1bfcbd8: defining beans [dataSource,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,requestDataValueProcessor,org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,customUserDetailsService,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#1,userDetailsDao,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#2,authenticationProvider,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#3]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Validated configuration attributes
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:01 PM org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain <init>
INFO: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@1eb620c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7206ea, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@240ba6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@78f1a0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@3f562f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@334482, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1d6d6cf, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1b0d8fc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@17599ab, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1bbdb89, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4a38ae, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@cf32f0]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator checkLoginPageIsntProtected
INFO: Checking whether login URL '/login' is accessible with your configuration
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1161 ms
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 27 16:17:02 IST 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1f7a4f8: defining beans [mainController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1bfcbd8
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Root mapping to handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome**] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome**.*] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome**/] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/admin**] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/admin**.*] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/admin**/] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/login.*] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/login/] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/403] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/403.*] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/403/] onto handler 'mainController'
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 440 ms
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\b2bAER_v1.0\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\LoginAttempt\WEB-kINF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5691 ms
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:15 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
Jul 27, 2016 4:17:15 PM org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory <init>
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
```

Comment: Can you share the failure stack-trace?

Comment: -haim raman ,here is my stacktrace for above code

Comment: I don't see any exception? the SQLErrorCodes  is not an error it's info?

Comment: -haim raman den i how come i need to connect to oracle db,all my account lockout code is implemented in a bean class but bean class is not connected to db to interact. how to solve this problem.please help me out .thanks in advance

Comment: What made you conclude that your application is not connecting to database.

Comment: yes exactly,I am not getting how to connect through bean classes rather than jdbc user service.

Answer (score 0):

My guess will be that one of the sqls from CustomUserDetailsService are the root cause.

The message “INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded:” is due to the fact the JdbcTemplate throw an exception.

**Make sure that the CustomUserDetailsService or the userDetailsDao are not swallowing any exceptions**

I would verify the following:

1. The syntax of all sqls is correct in the context of your database
   and schema (just try executing them directly on the database).
2. All placeholders (i.e. the '?') are poplated coreectly.
3. The data source pointing to the correct SID with the correct user
   name pointing to the desired schema

See also:
[spring security login not working with oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267920/spring-security-login-not-working-with-oracle)
    [Spring Security form login using database](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/)

Comment: using jdbc-service its working fine ,but problem is using custom user service for oracle database connection .please tell me the procedure from start how to connect using bean classes.